# 503 service unavailable error for .php files

Tags: php, jquery, web, server

I have stored my .php files in Hostinger. When I hit the files directly, they work. But when I use the same files in my website and hit it, they are giving 503 service unavailable error. And the same error is shown in postman as well.

503 error is shown when the server is down or is under maintenance. But the server is up as the response is shown when the .php file is hit directly in the browser.
Any solution for this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As for same php file I didn't get such an error when hosted on 000webhost, but I get this error on hostinger, and given that on 000webhost the php file can be accessed directly, but on hostinger you must pass through a "cloudlfare protection", I think this is the cause: upon requesting a file using a browser, the browser does not directly receive the file but a redirect or another command which it knows how to manage; if we request the same file programmatically, we receive "a redirect or another command" which we don't know how to manage.

This is the possible cause,don't know the solution.